# Using Visual Studio regex to find css name within class attribute

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010

Trying to use VS 2010 regex to make specific changes to a css class name.

Want to find every "required" that is in a class attribute.

```
1 - class="required"
2 - class="c1 required c2"
3 - class="c1"
4 - class="c1 required c2 c3"
5 - class="required c2"
6 - class="c1 c2"
7 - class="c1 c3 required "
```

So the expression should only match 1 2 4 5 7

The "required" word is used by some other stuff that can not be changed, so i can't just search for "required" and replace it.

Comment: Is this regex being used in the code of a program, or is this regex being used in the Find & Replace of the IDE? (They have different regex syntaxes.)

Comment: In the VS 2010 Find and Replace.  class.*=.*['""].*required.*['""]   was good enough to get my list i needed, would have been nice to do the replace. Was just faster to click on the 90 or so it found then try to figure out the replace syntax.

Comment: In the " ['""] " its a single and 2 double quotes, hard to read in the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are looking for a regex to use in the VS 2010 IDE Find & Replace box.

The Visual Studio 2010 IDE uses a non-standard regex syntax (See: [Regular Expressions (Visual Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx) - note that it uses curly braces to enclose capturing groups). If my understanding of the syntax and usage is correct, the following may do the trick:

Find this:

`{class[ \t]*=[ \t]*"[^"]*}required`

And replace it with this:

`\1replacementtexthere`

Note that I do not have VS 2010 so I cannot test the above solution.

Comment: Ended up using class.*=.*['""].*required.*['""] not perfect, can't do a replace with it, but it got me a much more condensed list then searching with just required.