# Remove specific class from all HTML tags

Tags: html, regex, visual-studio-2015

I have an HTML page where I need to remove all instances of particular class. I found a StackOverflow article, but the accepted solution doesn't work in Visual Studio 2015. The link for this article is listed below:
 [Using Visual Studio regex to find css name within class attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434702/using-visual-studio-regex-to-find-css-name-within-class-attribute)

I am trying

```
{class[ \t]*=[ \t]*"[^"]*}orgtemplate_tableentry
```

but it does not find the text.

Comment: jQuery has a `removeClass` that I've used plenty of times.

Comment: {class[ \t]*=[ \t]*"[^"]*}orgtemplate_tableentry

Comment: That post is for VS2010 that did not support a normal regex syntax. Now, you need to use `(class\s*=\s*"[^"]*)orgtemplate_tableentry` and replace with `$1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS2010 did not support normal regex syntax. Now, you need to replace `{...}` with parentheses to form a [*capturing group*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) that you can later refer to with `$n` backreferences (where `n` is the group ID).

So, use

```
(class\s*=\s*"[^"]*)orgtemplate_tableentry
```

and replace with `$1` to remove `orgtemplate_tableentry` that is located right after `class`, `=` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces, `"` and then 0+ chars other than `"`.

Comment: The RegEx you provided @Wiktor does accurately select class attributes containing the target class ("orgtemplate_tableentry"), but it leave an extra space in its place. For example, the value assigned to the class attribute, "orgtemplate_tableentry standard" is replaced with the value " standard". How can we remove the space that precedes the "standard" class?

Comment: The solution you provided @wiktor-stribiżew still leaves a space where the target class was removed.

Comment: Well, if conditional construct is supported, try `(class\s*=\s*"[^"]*?)(\s)*orgtemplate_tableentry(?(2)(\s*)|\s*)` to replace with `$1$3` (see [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28class%5cs*%3d%5cs*%22%5b%5e%22%5d*%3f%29%28%5cs%29*orgtemplate_tableentry%28%3f%282%29%28%5cs*%29%7c%5cs*%29&i=class%3d%22orgtemplate_tableentry+standard%22%0d%0aclass%3d%22standard+orgtemplate_tableentry%22%0d%0aclass%3d%22standard+orgtemplate_tableentry+complex%22&r=%241%243)).

Comment: For this concrete case, you may use an easier [`(class\s*=\s*"[^"]*?)\s*orgtemplate_tableentry\s*`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28class%5cs*%3d%5cs*%22%5b%5e%22%5d*%3f%29%5cs*orgtemplate_tableentry%5cs*&i=class%3d%22orgtemplate_tableentry+standard%22&r=%241) regex and replace with `$1` backreference.

Comment: The last RegEx you provided worked @wiktor-stribiżew. Thanks. I've accepted your answer as final. Thanks for your help; I really appreciate it :-)